# Alerting users which proxy they are using (in browser)

Tags: proxy, squid, google-chrome

I have a development network where users can use one of three proxies to browse from different places.  Its easy enough to get a plugin for browsers to let users switch but its hard to help users not browse out of the wrong one and get confused.  I currently just use a basic squid proxy for each but I can change the proxy, or the user plugin.

What I am looking for is ideas where users are clear on where they are browsing from - this could be a banner injected into all pages (but must not affect the sites themselves that are shown, so a frame or something, or even just a coloured border around a page), a toolbar that shows the proxy being used or some other kind of alert.

Any ideas?

--Chris

Comment: If you have a plugin which changes the proxy, why it can't show which proxy is in use?

Comment: A good question indeed but I can’t find one that does!  All the plugins have a single icon on the toolbar so unless you click on it and look you won’t know.l-it’s not obvious unless you remember to click on it.  Hence lots of opportunity to forget to check and browse out of the wrong proxy which is the root of my problem.

Comment: Well, it should be trivial to modify one so that it does. Find a developer. I'm sure your company has a bunch who are utterly bored and could do this in five minutes.